# Unable to add source via command line

Tags: ubuntu, source

I am trying to install latest version of glusterfs in Ubuntu
by running this command:

```
apt-add-repository ppa:semiosis/glusterfs-3.2
```

It does not give any result.

The session won't even close (Ctrl+C not working). I had to close the terminal window to end the session.

Error shown is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 88, in <module>
    ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py",
        line 80, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    curl.perform()
pycurl.error: (28, 'connect() timed out!')
```

Comment: Seems to be a network problem, try again later or find a different repository for glusterfs.

Comment: I tried using a proxy also still I am getting the above error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [this](https://launchpad.net/~semiosis/+archive/glusterfs-3.2) `This PPA is deprecated and will not get any updates.` so you may have to use glusterfs-3.3 and for downloading it use  [this](https://launchpad.net/~semiosis/+archive/ubuntu-glusterfs-3.3)

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/semiosis/ubuntu-glusterfs-3.3/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE main` 

deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/semiosis/ubuntu-glusterfs-3.3/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE main
```

Comment: I tried to add the above ppa also not getting output.. it stays there for some time and the above mentioned error is shown

Comment: are you accessing internet via proxy??

Comment: I have direct connection as well as proxy to run apt-get update commands I have to use proxy. Simple wget {sitename} will revert with out proxy

Comment: try this `export http_proxy=http://<proxy>:<port>`
 `export https_proxy=http://<proxy>:<port>`
`sudo -E apt-add-repository ppa:semiosis/ubuntu-glusterfs-3.3`